# Printwriter multiple lines with StringBuilder to CSV-file

Tags: java, timer, actionlistener, printwriter

I have 100 particles that all move with the help of `Timer` and `ActionListener`. I'm tracking the movement of my particles by saving the coordinates `x,y` in a `StringBuilder`. When the process is done I'm trying to print the results into a CSV-file, with an output that looks like this;

`time1, x1, y1, x2, y2, ... , xn, yn
time2, x1, y1, x2, y2, ... , xn, yn`, At the moment the timer stops after the particles have moved 100 times, I use a counter in my `ActionListener` to get this done. The problem is, my output in my CSV-file looks all messed up with more than 600 rows, it should only have 100 rows.

I've tried using different "newline"-commands like `\n`, `\r\n`, `%n`, but none of them gives me 100 lines.

The reason I want to use a `StringBuilder`and not just use `+`is because I want the code to work for as many particles as possible. If you have any other suggestions, I would gladly take them.

`Controller`:

```
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Controller extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    Model model;
    View view;
    private Timer timer;
    private int delta = 100;
    private StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
    private int counter = 0;
    private int time = 2000;

    public Controller(Model m, View v) {
        model = m;
        view = v;
        timer = new Timer(delta, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(time);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        counter++;

        csv.append(time);
        csv.append(",");
        csv.append(model.getPos());
        csv.append("\n");

        model.updatePos();
        view.repaint();
        time += delta * 0.001;

        if (counter>100) {
            timer.stop();
            PrintWriter pw;
            try {
                pw = new PrintWriter("data.csv");
                pw.println(csv);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Model`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Model {
    public int numberofparticles;
    public ArrayList<Particle> particlelist;
    public StringBuilder position = new StringBuilder();

    Model() {
        particlelist = new ArrayList<Particle>();
        numberofparticles = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofparticles; i++) {
            particlelist.add(new Particle());
        }
    }

    public void updatePos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofparticles; i++) {
        particlelist.get(i).x += 2*Math.cos(Math.random()*2*Math.PI);
        particlelist.get(i).y += 2*Math.sin(Math.random()*2*Math.PI);
        }
    }

    public StringBuilder getPos() {
        for (int i=0; i < numberofparticles; i++) {
            //position.setLength(0);
            position.append(particlelist.get(i).x);
            position.append(",");
            position.append(particlelist.get(i).y);
            position.append(",");
        }
        return position;
    }

    public class Particle {
        private double x;
        private double y;

        public Particle(double setX,double setY) {
            x = setX;
            y = setY;
        }

        Particle() {
            this(500+250*2*Math.cos(Math.random()*2*Math.PI),
                 300+150*2*Math.sin(Math.random()*2*Math.PI));
        }

        public double getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public double getY() {
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```

`View`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class View extends JPanel{
    Model model;

    View(Model m){
        model = m;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1010,610));
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        for (int i=0; i < model.numberofparticles; i++) {
        g.fillOval((int)(model.particlelist.get(i).getX()), (int) (model.particlelist.get(i).getY()), 3, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

`MyFrame`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    Model model;
    View view;

    MyFrame() {
        Model model = new Model();
        View view = new View(model);
        Controller control = new Controller(model, view);

        this.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        this.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, control);
        this.add(view);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Edit:
The code above is now complete and can be copy pasted to recreate the error.

In `Model`, I've commented out a line which would reset the `StringBuilder` after every run, but if I use this line then the data output to the CSV just becomes nothing. I have no idea why.

Comment: Could you be more precise about how the output differs from the expected? Is there just too much data? Are lines broken where they shouldn’t be? Maybe you should quote a few lines from the resulting file for us to see.

Comment: Also try [to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I am sure you problem can be illustrated with fewer lines of code, just a few particles and a few iterations.

Comment: Hey and thanks for the response! I put in the code so it can be copy-pasted. If you want with fewer iterations, change the `counter` to a lesser number in `Controller`, and if you want fewer particles, change "numberofparticles" in `Model`.

The output is hard to explain, but for example the "time" is not in the first column of each row. I have no idea where it is in the CSV, it looks like the time doesn't even get printed into the CSV.

Comment: If you take `View` and `MyFrame` out of the project and all references to them, do you still get the same undesired behaviour? Trying to help you minimize the example (you will want to do it only in a copy of the project, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing I believe that the error is that `StringBuilder position` is a field in the model. In your code each call to `getPos()` adds more to the same string builder. Instead `getPos()` should first create a new string builder and keep it locally while adding the coordinates to it.

Also `%n` in `StringBuilder.append()` will never give you a newline. Either `'\n'`, `"\r\n"` or `System.getProperty("line.separator")` should work, the last being the most correct.

As an aside, should the fields of the model be `public`? I think you can safely declare them `private` for better encapsulation.

Comment: This solved one of my problems, thank you! The other problem (why the time always said 0) was because I declared `time` as an `int`, so for every iteration I just got `time=0+0.1=0`. I changed it do double and then that solved aswell.

Comment: It’s a *nasty* trait of the `+=` operator in Java that it allows adding a `double` to an `int` and just silently truncates. It has confused many before you. I was told the problem was taken over from C (which just makes it worse, I think).